# Azure Active Directory B2C: running on two apps? (full-stack frontend + server-side web api)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to run Azure Active Directory B2C on two apps in tandem?
The platform have two things:

1. full-stack front-end application (Next.js) on a server. Needs: Authentication+Authorization.
2. ASP.Net Core Web API on another server. Needs: Authorization.

The platform would have social logins on the next.js client/server and then use that to authorize endpoints on either the next.js server api or the net core webapi.

What would be a general description to get this flow working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can integrate all of those clients with Azure AD B2C. You can find guides to integrate with all application types here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples

Your front end application sounds like a 'Single Page App' or 'Web App' as shown at that URL and your backend application would be under "API's".

The scenario you described is exactly what Azure AD B2C is for. Your user authenticates from a front-end application and then you can use their session token to authorize access on your backend service.

I would recommend you take a look at the guides on that page.